# Bootstrap file input button doesn't change

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using following code in my project:

```
<input class="btn btn-default btn-file" type="file" id="file" style="float:left; width: 250px" name='athletes_imageid'  value="" />
```

However my default button still stays on top of bootstrap one. Any way of fixing that?

[image]

Comment: http://www.abeautifulsite.net/whipping-file-inputs-into-shape-with-bootstrap-3/

Comment: Please do not use "bootstrap" tag, use "twitter-bootstrap" since it means something else

Answer (score 0):

Just put class to `<span>` like,

```
<span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
<input type="file" id="file" style="float:left; width: 250px" name='athletes_imageid'  value="" />
</span>
```

Comment: same thing I am afraid